# Insert bigint value into int column type Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, int, bigint

I need to insert some data from one table to another in Postgresql. Schema of the table I need to fill with data looks like this:

```
create table public.test_int_table(
    id                          int,
    description             text,
    hash_code               int
);
```

The issue is that id column in another table is of bigint type. So when I try to insert biting data into int column I get an exception:

```
insert into public.test_int_table
select * from public.test_table

SQL Error [22003]: ERROR: integer out of range
```

How can I trim bigint data for insert in Postgresql? Usual cast operator seems to work only for upcasting (from int to bigint and not otherwise).
Id it not a constantly increasing value and it fits into int in most of the cases so I don’t really care about loosing precision here.

Comment: Why not create  `int` columns  as `bigint` type in `public.test_int_table` table ?

Comment: This table should be preserved for some time not to break compatibility that is why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be quite dangerous, because you might get duplicates.  But you can use direct comparison and then handle the values that are too large.  The following "trims" them to `NULL`:

```
insert into public.test_int_table (id, description, hash_code)
    select (case when id < 2^31 - 1 then id::int end) as id,
           description, hash_code
    from public.test_table;
```

Note that this might totally mess up the data.  If you can change the value, then you could replace with a new value:

```
insert into public.test_int_table (id, description, hash_code)
    select dense_rank() over (order by id),
           description, hash_code
    from public.test_table;
```